# Scala / Akka and Spring Boot

Tags: spring, scala, spring-boot

As a newbie to Scala I noted that Spring Scala development within Pivotal has ceased thus am I correct that it should be avoided on a green field project to avoid integration. Is this assumption correct ?

To continue on the same topic; I have an existing Spring Boot application that provides endpoints and is currently operational. I need to reuse this jar in a new Akka cluster application, is calling

```
SpringApplication.run(classOf[Application])
```

in the Scala application the correct way to do this ?

Comment: This is obviously binary question. What does not work, what is your problem?

Comment: just an opinion but a big focus in the Scala ecosystem is slim library-oriented code as opposed to heavy framework stuff. The language itself has a couple of patterns for DI (implicits, self-type declarations) so I sortof see a DI framework as a heavyweight solution to a routine/lightweight problem. Just try idiomatic Scala with minimal libraries (Akka is the "framework" i use if any) & see how it goes. I did Spring for 2 years before Scala, really don't miss it.